# Phalcon not render view

Tags: php, phalcon

I tried to create multimodule phalcon application, but it cannot render view. For example Application\IndexController::indexAction not render view/index/index.phtml. All code here: [GitHub](https://github.com/3axap4eHko/Falconet)
Phalcon version: 0.9

Comment: I cloned the repo on my machine, when running it I'm getting: <html><head></head><body>Layout view<!-- Generated by 0.004667 seconds --></body></html>